# Unable to modify the border colour for the top navigation ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, master-page, page-layout, css

I want to define a blue border for all the top navigation ribbons, so using Firebug I have detected the classes which are responsible for the ribbon as shown in the below two images:-

So I use the following CSS rules inside my custom CSS document:-

```
.ms-cui-tabBody{
    border-color:#008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 !important;
    border-top-color:#008CD2 !important;

}
.ms-cui-tabBody.ms-cui-tabBody-gr{
    border-color:#008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 !important;
border-top-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
```

But unfortunately this has changed only the buttom boarder colour to be blue, while the “Calendar” tab still have green upper boarder, and “Page Option” tab have no upper boarder color ? can anyone advice on how I can change the boarder to be all blue?
Thanks.

Comment: From a user experience perspective it's not a wise decision to make all tabs uniform. They use different color for different purposes to make it easier for the user to find the correct tab. Take a look at your Word or Excel there are different colors too.

Comment: i know , but this what users is asking to have all colors within sharepoint to be blue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know that each ribbon has a different background color,  border, etc. to differentiate functionality. It is indeed not necessarily recommended to make them all uniform. Neverthelless, each ribbon has also it's own CSS selector and if you really want them all, you would need to change all, one by one and keep testing in various contexts (libraries, lists) as well as RTE context (Formatting, Image, etc.) - see here https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2010-Ribbon-CSS-Classes-Explained.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link, but it is talking about the tab it self, and tit did not mention how to chnage the boarder color for the ribbon ?

Comment: Also it shows SharePoint 2010, but he is working on 2013!